# Are there any service providers offering full email template editing integration?

Tags: mailchimp, sendgrid, email-templates, campaign-monitor, constantcontact

We developed our own home brew email template editing + previewing features in our Django webapp. It increasingly puts too much burden on us: previewing is not precise, special ad banner placements, and so on and so forth. We’d rather outsource that whole shebang to a provider, but ideally in a way that it seamlessly integrates into our webapp (could be an iframe, any way what is not alien in our webapp). We already use mailgun for email delivery.

Comparisons (http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/transactional-emailing-providers-mailjet-sendgrid-critsend) focus on marketing features, tracking, etc., but not integration or whitelabeling I'm looking for.

A very few providers (like SendGrid) mention whitelabeling of their editor, but I haven't really seen a page where I could feel that my problem was understood. I don't see clearly looking at the APIs how I would integrate an editor. Withelabeling the provider's email editor would still mean that my user would need to navigate to that website for the editing, and then back?

I'd really appreciate the answer of someone who went through this (before my question gets too many downvotes + I got beaten up with a stick), I'm sure we are not alone with this.

Comment: So far I'm going with Campaign Monitor, the feature is not complete yet, I'll keep you posted. https://help.campaignmonitor.com/topic.aspx?t=307

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there are no providers that provide an embeddable template editor. You'd have to rig something up yourself using e.g. TinyMCE, and then push the HTML output to one of the campaign tool APIs. There is a self-hosted solution called [mailtrain](https://github.com/andris9/mailtrain) but I don't know that it is easy to style or theme for custom UIs.

Comment: I'll look into this mailtrain. There's also mosaic.io

Comment: http://mosaico.io (I left out a letter in my comment above, couldn't edit it any more)

Comment: they that now mailtrain has support for mosaico.